# How do you return a template/html page with the promise of a function on that page returning a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

What I have is a function being invoked which takes some data and returns a templated HTML page.  It looks like this

```
  exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {
  var hashend = req.url.replace(/\//g, '');    
  var data = await admin.database().ref('item').child(hashend).once("value");  

  const templatedHtml = extract({food: data.val().food});
  return res.status(200).send(templatedHtml);
});
```

What I would like to do is after returning the templated HTML have it wait for the user to select something and then run the rest of the function.

What I have as a work around is 2 functions where the user hits an endpoint I return the page and then when the user selects the item the HTML page sends a post request to another endpoint which finishes the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cloud Functions, there is only a single round trip with the server for each request.  You can't pause a function to wait for user interaction.  Having two functions is really the only way to make this work, and of course, you'll have to make sure that the second function is passed whatever necessary state in order to continue any work from the first function.